# Moving a style in a class instead of in img tag makes the img not responsive anymore

Tags: html, css

This is my first post, I hope this will be clear!

I have an issue with HTML/CSS that I don't understand. One logo wasn't responsive on small screens so I added this class to my .css

```css
.project-logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

and added the class in this tag in my .tsx :

```
<img src={RandomLogopng} style={{display:'block'}} alt="Logo Random" className="project-logo"/>
```

It thus became responsive as I wanted on any screen. Now I want to clean my code a bit so I've tried moving the `display:block` inside the class directly, like this:

```css
.project-logo {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

and I delete it in the .tsx so it gives:

```
<img src={RandomLogopng} alt="Logo Random" className="project-logo"/>
```

But now, instead of being responsive on small screens, the logo disappears if the screen is too small compare to the logo's size! Can anyone help me understand why and how to clean this tag and still make the logo responsive, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `max width: 100%;` is not valid CSS-- it should be hyphenated as `max-width: 100%;`. Is this literally what is in your code, or a copy/paste error?

Comment: It's a copy mistake, thanks for saying! (I couldn't copy my code from my VM to my windows desktop so I wrote it...with mistakes)

Comment: Your css looks fine to me. As an idea to find the problem. Inspect the element in your Browsers Dev Tools in both cases to see with styles really getting applied to the element. Maybe you find any differences there.